# How to use NDSolve for going backward in time, if initial conditions are given at final point?

Tags: differential-equations

NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[10] == 1}, x, {t, 10, 0}]

Comment: The code you posted works as is....(Changing the order of the endpoints works, too: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[10] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {x'[t] == x[t], x[10] == 1};

sol = NDSolve[eqn, x, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If you want to see time run backwards

```
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. I actually have given initial conditions some where at critical point and then I have to go back in time. I also read in one of the group conversation that in this regard I have to define initial conditions on right hand side instead of left hand side but I didn't get this point.